# Filter specific record using Contains in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on an application where I need to filter a specific value but the reason I have only one parameter to filter it out.

```
string[] makes = { "UnitMakes:0:Enabled", "UnitMakes:0:UnitMake", "UnitMakes:0:Identity" };
var tt = makes.Where(x => x.Contains("UnitMake")).ToList();
```

Here **tt** returns a count of three but I need only the record **"UnitMakes:0:UnitMake"**. I can't add a where clause on a specific record that is because 0 is an index value that starts from 0 to any number. For example

```
UnitMakes:0:UnitMake
UnitMakes:0:Enabled
UnitMakes:0:Identity
UnitMakes:1:UnitMake
UnitMakes:1:Enabled
UnitMakes:1:Identity
UnitMakes:2:UnitMake
UnitMakes:2:Enabled
UnitMakes:2:Identity
```

I just want to return the UnitMake values not others.

Comment: `Where(x => x.EndsWith("UnitMake"))`? `Where(x => x.Contains(":UnitMake"))`?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on provided information you can do either:

```cs
.Where(x => x.EndsWith("UnitMake"))
```

or

```
.Where(x => x.Contains(":UnitMake"))
```